# Selecting JSON objects based on sibling with jq

Tags: json, jq

Given a list of objects like:

```
[
  { "key": 4, "value": { "a": "b" } },
  { "key": 5, "value": { "b": "c" } },
  { "key": 5, "value": { "c": "d" } }
]
```

I'd like to use `jq` to find all objects with key "5" provided that the previous item in the list has key "4". Only the middle entry should match.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json isn't correct but assuming you fix it this approach using [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) may work for you

```
  reduce .[] as $o (
    { found:false, collected:[] }                        # reduce state
  ; if .found|not then                                   # until 4 found
      if $o.key == 4 then .found = true else . end       # keeping searching for 4
    else                                                 # after 4 is found
      if $o.key == 5 then .collected += [$o] else . end  # gather up all the 5's 
    end
  )
| .collected                                             # return collected
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHLboMwEEX3/oorQGqrIlawoeJLEAvHDAmNhVM/KlVNvp0OpmmTRRRlNh6Nj4@uPO8f8wxY6oMiFG0H6ZAZPAtwfWMwYerrQWpHOZTRmpSnvmbuhBuVnm3OS0/secM4oIim42Q8/I4m3K8UYfKjRrmGEOuUVZkp9vSFpuGr6FrdaOBtIBBnRQHiyVm0JzqM0xaOpFW7pRuMRRmVEX@0UsjBEyswutvxqt94f/@G1wZtZrqrjCm2kjmLcIDUenmD6slhTRfNL@J4aXksqSUf7PS/PCHmuRXLchPOmdQocySfUgfinoeSj2ST8IJP@SVWXWObBVN3MbVgfcRE9wM)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I hadn't considered `reduce`. I tweaked it to require the immediate preceding sibling, rather than any previous sibling. Do you have any improvements? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDLbsIwEEX3/oorw6KoUVawCcqXRFkYewIplk0TG6lq@fZ0nJZHi1CYjT3Xx3ceb@/D0JGJmpBXNVSPuceLAD5x6OjY@tgXcNHaDNpbSzqQKcDkCQ9ihl@/PqhAYo22QX72gnKGK@R7@kBZYjXml9ezvETYkcN0zBBdaC1/aHx0RiQtv/SJ1xLV3Ncsk@3p5zUlTH7d9FRyR2KBZyMNGGLnrgtJbtdkGKpxf5KnkQWWGeRR2Uh8Z1HxITeS93fKbrHVX2yTMD2J6YSZe@xfUZMwmnRrErYdMVF/Aw "jq – Try It Online")

Comment: I would go with whatever best expresses your requirements.  If they get complex you might want to solve this by using [`def`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DefiningFunctions) to create a helper function or two.  You could also use recursive functions directly.  e.g. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/LDoIwEEX3/YqbriQhRBLYgHwJYQF0ABXxhSZE@XbsA4nIgll0OndO504P12EQVOBO6S2vAgaoqjg/GqEKYF@gpqZsq52LtqIGdLq0Hai@k@5rwom3iXOkDlEE32BKsoGNE7tBgvdoYOmHmMKoADVCTzM5ZGzdWPYxM/YMNsZkrP9iwRgv19GG6gxZ/F0nGYZYqi9wOZoH8GzwZ1o/SN6lmMrEM44evf2L@XMsU1i@iuUKE0vsz1QojFanFQorNcaSDw "jq – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

> find all objects with key "5" provided that the previous item in the list has key "4".

If the goal is to find all objects with key `5` provided that the **immediately** preceding item has key `4`, then the following is an efficient solution:

```
foreach .[] as $d ({};
    if .previous == 4 and $d.key == 5
    then .emit = $d 
    else .emit = null 
    end | .previous = $d.key;
    .emit | select(.))
```

### Example

Here is an example which also illustrates that the solution using `reduce` elsewhere on this page produces inaccurate results relative to the above interpretation.

```
[
  { "key": 4, "value": { "a": "b" } },
  { "key": 5, "value": { "b": "c" } },
  { "key": 5, "value": { "c": "d" } },
  { "key": 4, "value": { "d": "e" } },
  { "key": 5, "value": { "e": "f" } }
]
```

Result:

```
{"key":5,"value":{"b":"c"}}
{"key":5,"value":{"e":"f"}}
```